Minimization of smooth objective with conic constraint
I am interested in deriving first-order optimality conditions for
\begin{equation}
\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}f(x)\\
\text{s.t. }x\in\mathcal{K}
\end{equation}
where $f$ is a smooth function and $\mathcal{K}$ is a cone, for concreteness let's take
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{K}=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\text{ s.t. }x_{1}\geq\|x_{2:n}\|_{2}\rbrace
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
x=\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2:n}
\end{bmatrix}, \,x_{1}\in\mathbb{R},\,x_{2:n}\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}
\end{equation}
the optimization problem is then equivalently reformulated as
\begin{equation}
\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}f(x)\\
\text{s.t. }x_{1}\geq \|x_{2:n}\|_{2}
\end{equation}
If the constraint $x_{1}-\|x_{2:n}\|_{2}\geq 0$ and the objective $f(x)$ were both smooth, then I would form a Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(x,z)=f(x)-z\cdot(x_{1}-\|x_{2:n}\|_{2})
\end{equation}
and then require that
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{x}\mathcal{L}=0\\
z\geq 0,\,x_{1}-\|x_{2:n}\|_{2}\geq 0,\,z\cdot(x_{1}-\|x_{2:n}\|_{2})=0
\end{equation}
however $\|\cdot\|_{2}$ is not a continuously differentable function and so $\nabla_{x}\mathcal{L}$ isn't defined everywhere.
I was able to recover optimality conditions in the literature by replacing $\nabla_{x}\|x\|_{2}$ by the subderivative but am not sure why this works. Any pointers or references on deriving optimality conditions for this problem would be greatly appreciated.
